# Изменение стилей элементов массива JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
  Есть разметка:
<div>
<img id="next" src="img/right.png">
<img id="prev" src="img/left.png">
<h6 class="Place">А</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Б</h6>
<h6 class="Place">В</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Г</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Д</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Е</h6>
</div>
```

Изначально у всех элементов с классом ".Place" цвет черный, кроме первого (у первого красный). Как сделать так, что бы при клике на "#next", цвет второго элемента стал красным, а предыдущего черным и так дальше по кругу. И наоборот при клике на "#prev" цвет последнего элемента стал красным, а первого черным и так по кругу в обратом направлении?

Долблю через это:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Place');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
elements[i].classList.add(.css('color', '#982518'));
};
});
```

Но тогда все элементы становятся красными. Вопрос в том как управлять стилем отдельного элемента массива и делать это по кругу при каждом клике?

Comment: Покажи полную разметку html/css/js

Comment: Это вся разметка на данный момент.

Answer (score 1):

Для вашей разметки:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var nInd = 0;
  var aObjs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.Place'));
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    aObjs[nInd].classList.remove('active');
    if (e.target.id == 'next') { nInd = (nInd + 1 < aObjs.length) ? nInd + 1 : 0; } 
    else if (e.target.id == 'prev') { nInd = (nInd - 1 > -1) ? nInd - 1 : aObjs.length - 1; }
    aObjs[nInd].classList.add('active');
  });
  aObjs[nInd].classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<img id="next" src="img/right.png">
<img id="prev" src="img/left.png">
<h6 class="Place">А</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Б</h6>
<h6 class="Place">В</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Г</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Д</h6>
<h6 class="Place">Е</h6>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!) Как вы понимаете, куда копать при решении той или иной задачи?) Я вот JQuery колупаю третью неделю и никогда бы до такого не додумался...(((

Comment: @101 это очень простая задача, а здесь их десяток в день проходит - практика. Но, как говорится - "век живи - век учись" - иногда, вижу такие оригинальные решения, что сам на стуле подскакиваю))

Comment: А сколько по времени вы JQuery изучаете?)

Comment: @101 извините, но с jQuery я не дружу принципиально, предпочитаю чистый JavaScript. А по времени... всё началось с ассемблера на ZX-Spectrum (если это что-то говорит Вам)))

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот такое решение

```js
var pag = document.getElementsByClassName('Place');
var pagLength = pag.length;
var next =document.getElementById('next');
var prev =document.getElementById('prev');
var actionPos = 0;
var k = 0;





function leftRight(e) {
 for(i = 0; i < pagLength-1; i++) {
  pag[i].classList.remove('actionColor')
 }
 if(e == 'right') {
  if(actionPos == pagLength-1) {
   actionPos = 0
  } else {
   actionPos++;
  }
 }
 if(e == 'left') {
  if(actionPos == 0) {
   actionPos = pagLength-1;
  } else {
   actionPos--;
  }
 }
 for(i = 0; i < pagLength; i++) {
  pag[i].classList.remove('actionColor')
 }
 pag[actionPos].classList.add('actionColor');
}
```

```css
.actionColor {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
 <div>
        <img id="next" alt="right" onclick="leftRight('right')">
        <img id="prev" alt="left" onclick="leftRight('left')">
        <h6 class="Place actionColor">А</h6>
        <h6 class="Place">Б</h6>
        <h6 class="Place">В</h6>
        <h6 class="Place">Г</h6>
        <h6 class="Place">Д</h6>
        <h6 class="Place">Е</h6>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Как пришли к такому решению?Сколько JQuery изучаете?

Comment: это чистый js. jquery изучал когда только начинал учить js, тогда было очень легко с ним, а сейчас пишу только на чистом